# Showing that $\mathbb{C}^2$ is irreducible as an $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-module

Tags: modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) = \{A \in \operatorname{M}_2(\mathbb{C}) \mid \operatorname{tr}(A)= 0\}$.

How to prove that $\mathbb{C}^2$ is an irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-module?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong definition of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, it should be $\{A \in M_{2}(\Bbb C) : \text{tr}(A) = 0 \}$ .

Notice that $e = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 }$ acts as follows : $e v_1 = 0$ and $ev_2 = v_1$. Similarly, for $f = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 }$ we have $fv_1 = v_2$ and $fv_2 = 0$. Here $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (0,1)$.

From this it is easy to conclude that any $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-module spanned by a single  vector $w \in \Bbb C^2 \backslash \{0\}$ should be everything.

Comment: If  $e_1 = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 }$ ,  $e_2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 }$ .  $f = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 }$   acts as follows : $e_1 v_1 = 0$ and $e_1 v_2 = v_1$  and $e_2 v_1 = v_2$ and $e_2  v_2 = 0$ , $fv_1 = v_1$ and $fv_2 = (0,-1)$. where $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_2 = (0,1)$. i know that $sl_2 = span\{e_1, e_2, f \} $ ;  but i don't understand how it's answers the irreducibility of C^2.

Comment: @AliNoumSaliTraore Let $w = av_1 + bv_2$ be a non-zero vector of $\Bbb C^2$. Can you show that $w, ew, fw$ spans $\Bbb C^2$ ? (I kept my notation because this is the standard one, what you wrote $f$ is usually written $h$).

Comment: thanks  for your reply, i don't understand very well, but  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the answer of @NicolasHemelsoet, there is an argument which you may view as simpler, but which does not generalize (say to the analogous question for $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C)$).

Suppose that there is a non-trivial subspace $V$ in $\mathbb C^2$ that is invariant under the action of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$. Then $V$ has to have dimension one, so it is of the form $\mathbb C\cdot v$ for some nonzero vector $v\in\mathbb C^2$. But then for each $A\in\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ we have to have $Av\in \mathbb C\cdot v$ by invariance, which says that $v$ is an eigenvector for each $A\in \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$. But already the elements $e_1$ and $e_2$ from above do not have a joint eigenvector.